# How to stretch a shape (view) in iOS, using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am in the process of developing an app and I have hit a minor roadblock in the animation stage of the process. I am unable to figure out how to animate a view stretching, using Swift. Thanks.

Comment: Well thats just lovely, how are you doing your animation at the moment? Can you show some code? - As it stands your question is not detailed enough for someone to give you an accurate answer for you situation.

Comment: Hey OP, please consider accepting my answer if you found it helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

You can scale your `UIView` like this:

```
myView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(x, y)
```

If you leave the `x` at `1` you could stretch to the `y` direction only and the other way around.

Hope that helps :)